# Remove last element from list in Elixir?

Tags: elixir

How would you simply remove 20 from the end of this example?

```
[46, 238, 64, 30, 105, 136, 98, 75, 23, 157, 11, 20]
```

Comment: The easiest way to write it is actually`Enum.drop(list, -1)`. Though it might not necessarily be the fastest.

Answer (score 19):

**fastest solution that I know of with @mudasobwa's one

solution 1**:

```
x |> Enum.reverse() |> tl() |> Enum.reverse()
```

Some other solutions:
**solution 2**:

```
[k] = Enum.chunk(x, length(x)-1)
```

**solution 3**:

```
List.delete_at(x, length(x)-1)
```

**solution 4**:

```
x |> List.to_tuple() |> Tuple.delete_at(length(x)-1) |> Tuple.to_list
```

---

An even more interesting question, is how to do that the fastest way ? let's benchmark it !

I got the following result using [Benchee](https://github.com/PragTob/benchee), each solution was computed 50000 times, and I used a list created with `Enum.to_list(1..10_000)`

```
Name                                  ips        average  deviation         median         99th %
mudasobwa's solution              14.80 K       67.57 μs    ±34.17%          79 μs          91 μs
solution 1                        14.79 K       67.59 μs    ±33.96%          79 μs          91 μs
solution 4                        10.71 K       93.38 μs    ±32.67%          81 μs         201 μs
Roman Rabinovich's solution        8.45 K      118.33 μs    ±18.27%         118 μs         171 μs
OneSneakyMofo's solution           5.07 K      197.34 μs    ±13.60%         193 μs         331 μs
dawner's solution                  4.57 K      219.00 μs    ±11.87%         216 μs      256.23 μs
solution 3                         3.41 K      292.91 μs    ±20.01%         290 μs      506.64 μs
solution 2                         0.83 K     1205.52 μs    ±22.25%        1105 μs     2061.77 μs

Comparison: 
mudasobwa's solution              14.80 K
solution 1                        14.79 K - 1.00x slower
solution 4                        10.71 K - 1.38x slower
Roman Rabinovich's solution        8.45 K - 1.75x slower
OneSneakyMofo's solution           5.07 K - 2.92x slower
dawner's solution                  4.57 K - 3.24x slower
solution 3                         3.41 K - 4.33x slower
solution 2                         0.83 K - 17.84x slower
```

Comment: Nice. Can you benchmark mine?

Comment: Please follow the code style guide: start the pipe with a term, not with a function: `x |> Enum.reverse() |> tl() |> Enum.reverse()` (and use parentheses in calls to functions.)

Comment: Thank you @mudasobwa by the way, the references on those 2 coding styles:
https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#parentheses-pipe-operator
https://github.com/christopheradams/elixir_style_guide#parentheses-pipe-operator

Comment: @OneSneakyMofo, I updated the test bench report. I added your solution, since it answers to the question.

Comment: why not erlangs {NewList, _} = lists:split(List, (length(List)-1))

Comment: @Roman Rabinovich, I updated the test bench with your solution. In elixir, it is written this way: ```{k, _} = :lists.split((length(x)-1), x)``` x being the list, and k the list minus its last element. (I am afraid you mixed up arg1 and arg2 in you solution)

Answer (score 10):

You could do:

```
List.pop_at(x, -1)
{20, [46, 238, 64, 30, 105, 136, 98, 75, 23, 157, 11]}
```

Answer (score 2):

While the solution given by Nathan Ripert is good enough, it’s not exactly fastest.

[`Enum.reverse/1`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/0429cdd95f10abe2f5b3d188c2c3574132cae474/lib/elixir/lib/enum.ex#L2019) is a general-purpose function that goes through `reduce`.

Pure erlang [`:lists.reverse/1`](http://erlang.org/doc/man/lists.html#reverse-1) should be faster (very very slightly):

```
x |> :lists.reverse() |> tl() |> :lists.reverse()
```

Comment: He wanted an answer from Elixir not Erlang.

Comment: @OneSneakyMofo This is Elixir. Erlang does not have pipes.

Comment: @mudasobwa actually, during first computation your solution was slightly faster, and now that I am rerunning it, it is slightly slower... since the difference is quite small, it might not be reliably measured by the test bench.

Answer (score 1):

So many ways to do this. Here's another:

```
[46, 238, 64, 30, 105, 136, 98, 75, 23, 157, 11, 20]
|> Enum.reject(&(&1 == 20)
```

Comment: This will remove all occurrences of `20`, not _“`20` from the end of this example”_ as stated in OP.

Comment: Yes, I am aware, but I answered the question. He wants to " simply remove 20 from the end of this example" which is what this does.